# Can I fake the originating hyperlink of one remote page to say that it came from another page?

Tags: php, html

Let's say that I have a website:

```
www.anywhere.com/test.php
$source = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

There's a website that links to mine.

```
www.nowhere.com/remote1.html
<a href="www.anywhere.com/test.php">Link</a>
```

And another that does the same thing

```
www.somewhere.com/remote2.html
<a href="www.anywhere.com/test.php">Link</a>
```

If I click on Link on `www.somewhere.com/remote2.html`, `www.anywhere.com/test.php $source` will be `www.somewhere.com/remote2.html`.

I was wondering if there would be any way that `somewhere.com/remote2.html` disguise itself such that when its link is clicked, `anywhere.com/test.php $source` will be another URL (for example `www.nowhere.com/remote1.html`)

If I were to have a webservice where I accept request from accredited websites, I would need to be assured that nobody is able to access my webservice by faking their URI with those from accredited websites.

Thanks

Comment: It is the browser that sends the HTTP_REFERER to your service. It can easily be faked and should not be trusted

Comment: I see, would there any security measure I can take? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any request header can be faked. These are sent by the client and can easily be spoofed. You should not rely on these values. There's no guarantee that it'll be accurate.

In PHP, you can use `cURL` to spoof it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Referer: http://some-accredted-website.com/', 
));
```

There are even browser extensions / plugins that does this. For example, there's [*Modify Headers*](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) addon for Firefox. There are even online services like [*Fiddler*](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that lets you alter these values.

**Bottom line:** never rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on being accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The referer is just a field in the HTTP head so you can either create a HTTP request manually, or use an application that lets you set any fields to any values, which is easier because you don't need to calculate lengths manually.